# How to perform join on a field which needs to be split?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, oracle11g

I'm querying like below.
So far it worked. But recently table2's season column started containing multiple (any number) comma-separated seasons.
table1's seasons are always single. How to join the tables now keeping the space-season handling I already have (it works as I want to)?
Like table2's seasons might be ('winter, allweather, fall') and there are 3 separate rows in table1 with these seasons. I need to select other columns from table 1 based on this join.
For example:

```
Table2:
          SEASON                    DESCRIPTION           LETTER  
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|         Winter           |        DescriptionW        |   A   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|    Winter, Allweather    |        Description2        |   B   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|                          |        DescriptionS        |   C   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|

Table1:
          SEASON                    SOMETHINGELSE              ART
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|         Winter           |        SomethingElseW      |       1       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|         Allweather       |        SomethingElseA      |       2       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|            Fall          |        SomethingElseF      |       3       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|

Table0:
          ART                         STUFF                     LETTER      KOL
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         1                |        Stuff1              |          A       | 0  |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         2                |        Stuff2              |          B       | 20 |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         3                |        Stuff3              |          C       | 30 |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
```

And I need:

```
SELECT table1.season, table0.art, table0.stuff, sum(table0.kol), table2.letter,  from table0 
inner join table1 on table0.art = table1.art
inner join table2 on (
table0.letter = table2.letter and
table2.season = case when table2.season != ' ' then table1.season end
) where table2.description = 'lkjhgfd' group by table1.season, table0.art, table0.stuff table2.letter having sum(table0.kol) > 0,
```

I'm not the author of the model and I'm not allowed to change it.
There is that blank space thing in table2. It is important. It means that if there is no space, then perform join on 2 conditions, if blank then leave only first condition after on.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results in a *text table* format.

Comment: comma separated lists are a SQL Antipattern. Bill Karwin gives an excellent summary in Chapter 2 of his book *SQL Antipatterns: Avoing the Pitfalls of Database Programmming*  available at Amazon and other ine booksellers : https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557

Comment: edited, please have a look now (the real structure is even worse)

Comment: If possible, I'd do that join in the application. Any SQL would look pretty confusing to someone maintaining later on.

Comment: It's like a task, hard to explain, it is a project but first i absolutely need to do it in a a single query

Answer (score 3):

You should fix table2!!! Storing multiple values in a string is bad -- and efforts should go into fixing the data model rather than trying to query it.

If you are stuck with a bad, bad, bad data model, you can use mechanisms such as `like`:

```
select ...
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 gr 
     on ', ' || table2.season || ',' like '%, ' || table1.season || ',%';
```

Comment: +10 this is the approach i would use. deal with those pesky missing commas before the first in the list, and after end of the list, by appending them, then we just check for a value "in the list" that falls between commas.(much more straightforward than the gyrations of doing three checks) and we do need those commas, for the more general case where we need to match a entire value and avoid matching a substring +10

Comment: Thanks, it works of there were no spaces but there is a space possibility which i need to handle separately

Comment: @Ivanichivanich . . . Spaces are easily handled.  I don't think they were in the original version of your question.

Comment: handled here you mean?

Comment: @Ivanichivanich . . . I edited the answer to support spaces after the comma.

Comment: thanks, i meant different spaces, i have a requirement where I join by 2 clauses when the cell has either one or many seasons, or by 1 clause if there is a blank space instead of seasons

Answer (score 0):

As you were told: bad data model, **bad**. Don't do that.

Anyway, have a look at the following example which shows how I understood the problem. Read comments within code. Basically, you'll have to split those comma-separated values into rows in order to join them to `season` in another table.

```
SQL>    with
  2  -- sample data
  3  table1 (season, string) as
  4    (select 'winter', 'ice' from dual union all
  5     select 'autumn', 'apples' from dual union all
  6     select 'summer', 'swimming' from dual union all
  7     select 'spring', 'flowers'  from dual
  8    ),
  9  table2 (id, season) as
 10    (select 1, 'spring'        from dual union all
 11     select 2, 'spring,summer' from dual
 12    )
 13  -- this is what you need
 14  select c.id, c.season, a.string
 15  from table1 a join
 16    (select b.id,
 17            b.season,
 18            regexp_substr(b.season, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) season_one
 19     from table2 b cross join
 20          -- split comma-separated values into rows
 21          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 22                              connect by level <= regexp_count(b.season, ',') + 1
 23                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 24    ) c on c.season_one = a.season
 25  order by c.id;

        ID SEASON        STRING
---------- ------------- --------
         1 spring        flowers
         2 spring,summer swimming
         2 spring,summer flowers

SQL>
```